# How to delete an image using PHP & MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql

I was wondering if some one can give me an example on how to delete an image using PHP & MySQL?

The image is stored in a folder name thumbs and another named images and the image name is stored in a mysql database.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to delete a file via PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2371408/how-to-delete-a-file-via-php)

Answer (score 8):

**Delete the file:**

```
unlink("thumbs/imagename");

unlink("images/imagename");
```

**Remove from database**

```
$sql="DELETE FROM tablename WHERE name='imagename'"

$result=mysql_query($sql);
```

Assuming `name` is the the name of the field in the database holding the image name, and `imagename` is the image's name.

All together in code:

```
$imgName='sample.jpg';
$dbFieldName='name';
$dbTableName='imageTable';
unlink("thumbs/$imgName");
unlink("images/$imgName");
$sql="DELETE FROM $dbTableName WHERE $dbFieldName='$imgName'";
mysql_query($sql);
```

Answer (score 1):

try this code :

```
$img_dir = 'image_directory_name/';
$img_thmb = 'thumbnail_directory_name/';// if you had thumbnails

$image_name = $row['image_name'];//assume that this is the image_name field from your database

//unlink function return bool so you can use it as conditon
if(unlink($img_dir.$image_name) && unlink($img_thmb.$image_name)){
    //assume that variable $image_id is queried from the database where your image record your about to delete is...
    $sql = "DELETE FROM table WHERE image_id = '".$image_id."'";
    $qry = mysql_query($sql);
}else{
   echo 'ERROR: unable to delete image file!';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for actual code or just the idea behind it?

You'll need to query the db to find out the name of the file being deleted and then simply use unlink to delete the file in question.

so here's some quick code to get you started

```
<?php
$thumb_dir = "path/to/thumbs/";
$img_dir = "path/to/images/";

/* query your db to get the desired image
   I'm guessing you're using a form to delete the image?
   if so use something like $image = $_POST['your_variable'] to get the image 
   and query your db */

// once you confirm that the file exists in the db check to see if the image 
// is actually on the server

if(file_exists($thumb_dir . $image . '.jpg')){
    if (unlink($thumb_dir . $image . '.jpg') && unlink($img_dir . $image . '.jpg'))
        //it's better to use the ID rather than the name of the file to delete it from db
        mysql_query("DELETE FROM table WHERE name='".$image."'") or die(mysql_error());
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if(!empty($_GET['pid']) && $_GET['act']=="del")
{
    $_sql = "SELECT * FROM mservices WHERE pro_id=".$_GET['pid'];

    $rs = $_CONN->Execute($_sql);
    if ($rs->EOF) {
        $_MSG[] = "";
        $error = 1;
    }

    if ($rs)
        $rs->close();
    if (!$error) {

    $_Image_to_delete = "select pro_img from mservices where pro_id=".$_GET['pid'];
    $trial=$_CONN->Execute($_Image_to_delete);
    $img = trim(substr($trial,7));
    unlink($_DIR['inc']['product_image'].$img);


      $_sql = "delete from mservices where pro_id=".$_GET['pid'];
        $_CONN->Execute($_sql);
        header("Location: ".$_DIR['site']['adminurl']."mservices".$atend."suc".$_DELIM."3".$baratend);
        exit();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$_sql = "SELECT * FROM mservices WHERE pro_id=".$_GET['pid'];

$rs = $_CONN->Execute($_sql);
if ($rs->EOF) {
    $_MSG[] = "";
    $error = 1;
}

if ($rs)
    $rs->close();
if (!$error) {

$_Image_to_delete = "select pro_img from mservices where pro_id=".$_GET['pid'];
$trial=$_CONN->Execute($_Image_to_delete);
$img = trim(substr($trial,7));
unlink($_DIR['inc']['product_image'].$img);


  $_sql = "delete from mservices where pro_id=".$_GET['pid'];
    $_CONN->Execute($_sql);
    header("Location: ".
```