# Unlink but file date size remains on new file

Tags: php, windows, unlink

I am trying to overwrite a file on a windows server.
The file contents does get over written, but the file date remains unchanged.

I have tried the following;

```
unlink(DUMP_FILENAME); 
file_exists(DUMP_FILENAME);
```

This returns false, so file should be gone, correct?

```
file_put_contents(DUMP_FILENAME,$data,0);
```

File gets new data, but date is the same as prior to the `unlnk()`
Why would that be?

Edit: Tried deleting the file from windows, the date on the file after the PHP script is run remains as prior to the windows delete!

The reason I was trying to delete first, rather than just overwriting, was I wanted the date of the file to change.

Comment: How do you query the date?

Comment: Assuming you mean the file's creation date, this is a known behaviour of the Windows file system.  If you delete a file and then recreate it (within some small period of time) it will magically inherit the previous creation date.  This is usually the sensible thing to do.  (Sorry, I can't find any references at the moment.)  I believe the only workaround is to explicitly set the creation date yourself, though I no idea whether that is possible in PHP - or to ignore the creation date and use the modification date instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you mean the file's creation date, this is a known behaviour of the Windows file system.  If you delete, move, or rename a file and then recreate it (within some small period of time) it will magically inherit the previous creation timestamp.

While this is surprising, it is usually the sensible thing to do, e.g., this sequence of events is typical for a text editor when you save your changes, and clearly the creation date of a file shouldn't change just because you've modified it.

Possible workarounds;

- Create the new file with a unique name, then move it over top of the original file.  It must be a genuine atomic move (i.e., a call to [`MoveFileEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365240%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) with `MOVEFILE_REPLACE_EXISTING`, or equivalent) rather than deleting the old file and renaming the new one.  I don't know whether or not you can do this with PHP.
- Explicitly set the creation date yourself ([`SetFileInformationByHandle`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365539%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)).  Again, no idea whether PHP allows you to do this.
- Wait long enough between deleting the file and recreating it.  I don't know how long "long enough" is and it might vary between different Windows versions or even within a Windows version for unpredictable reasons, so unless you can find some detailed documentation doing it this way probably isn't reliable.
- Don't bother; make sure you use the modification date rather than the creation date when applying whatever logic it is that cares about the timestamps.

Answer (score 2):

[From the manual (First comment)](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unlink.php), I’ve noticed this too in the past.

The `unlink()` is not about removing file, it’s about removing a file name to the body of data. The manpage should say: unlink - delete a name and possibly the file it refers to.

Most of the time a file has just one name — removing it will also remove (free, deallocate) the `body' of file. That's the simple, usual case.

But a file’s body may *also* be kept alive' (still using diskspace) by a process holding the file open.

*So basically, the body (contents) of the file will not be deallocated (will not free disk space) as long as the process holds it open. (The current thread that wrote to it)*

**So instead of using `filectime()` to check for changes and creation, use `filemtime()`.**

Comment: So how does that explain the *date* is the same?

Comment: Its because its contents are still on disk and only gone after the end of execution, it will basically link() back to the body of data.. test it use unlink in one file and then try read the file in **another** request or file. It wont work.

Comment: You will, a file is never actually deleted *zero-ed*, just its name/link in the symbolic, hard link, MFT reference is removed. Look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17548906/completely-deleting-a-file-from-server

Comment: So I would need to call a "delete" script, then a separate "save new" script?

Comment: Can you make an example to show, because there shouldn't be a reason to delete the file in PHP and then recreate it with different data in the same request, just write what data you want without deleting/unlinking it.

Comment: @Loz, my only reason for the convoluted overwrite was to try and get the date to change.

Comment: "But A file's body may also be kept alive' (still using diskspace) by a process holding the file open."  - true in Linux but not Windows.  In Windows if a process has a file open you can't unlink it (unless the process gave permission).

Comment: Does PHP provide a way to explicitly set the timestamps on a file?  (See my comment to the question.)

Comment: touch() only changes access time, not creation time.

Comment: reason for delete added to question

Comment: You cant natively, why would you want to, because you want the file on your system so its not about when it was created its about when it was changed, so instead of using filectime() to check for changes/creation use filemtime(). As its the DATA that changes not the file. Its simply an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)