# How to delete a file via PHP - receiving error

Tags: php

Trying to delete files from server but receive this error:

unlink(): cURL does not allow unlinking in...

Here is my code:

```
foreach($fDel as $del=>$delval){
$paths = array("art/images/", "art/smallthumbs/", "art/thumbs/");
$imgid = $delval['img_id'];

$fileNm = $delval['img_fname'];
foreach($paths as $x=>$path) { 
$file = URL . $path . $fileNm.".jpg";
unlink($file);  
}

}
```

Comment: Use a server path, not a URL.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to delete a file via PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2371408/how-to-delete-a-file-via-php)

Comment: Why don't you echo `$file` to see if it contains the right file path?

Comment: Yes have checked that and the path is correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[unlink](https://www.php.net/unlink) PHP function delete files by full root server path, so you must:

```
if ( file_exists(__DIR__ .'/'. $path . $fileNm .".jpg") ) {
    unlink(__DIR__ .'/'. $path . $fileNm .".jpg");
} else {
    die('File not exists!');
}
```

where `art/images` dir must placed in `__DIR__`.

Comment: Due to the folder structure I had to trim of access folders but otherwise it worked. Thanks