# update values in table php-mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have this table:

```
+----+------------+-----------------------+
| ID | ID_PRODUCT | LINK_DOWNLOAD         |
+----+------------+-----------------------+
| 1  |  2369      | folder/2015.03.12.pdf |
| 2  |  3694      | folder/2014.01.10.pdf |
| 3  |    56      | folder/2016.09.25.pdf |
+----+------------+-----------------------+
```

End code php:

```
  <form action="upload_file.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="upload_file"><br>
    <label for="UploadFileField"></label><br>
    <input type="file" name="UploadFileField"/>
    <input type="submit" name="UploadButton" value="Upload" /><br>
    <input type ="text" name="UPLOAD_COD" />
  </form>


<?php
include "bd_cnx.php";
if (isset ($_FILES['UploadFileField'])){
  $UploadName = $_FILES['UploadFileField'] ['name'];
  $UploadName = mt_rand (100000, 999999).$UploadName;
  $UploadTmp = $_FILES['UploadFileField'] ['tmp_name'];
  $UploadType = $_FILES['UploadFileField'] ['type'];
  $FileSize = $_FILES['UploadFileField'] ['size'];

  $UploadName = preg_replace("#[^a-z0-9.]#i", "", $UploadName);

  if(($FileSize > 1250000)){
    die ("Error - File to big");
  }

  if(!$UploadTmp) {
    die ("No File Selected");
  }
  else {
    if (move_uploaded_file($UploadTmp, "Upload/$UploadName")) {
            $UPLOAD_COD = $_POST['UPLOAD_COD'];
            $sql = "INSERT INTO download (ID_PRODUCT,LINK_DOWNLOAD) VALUES ('$UPLOAD_COD','Upload/$UploadName')";
            $result = $conn->query($sql);
        echo '<script> alert("Successfully inserted"); window.location ="/index.php";</script>';
    }
  }
}
 ?>
```

2015.03.12.pdf file is today updating and becomes 2016.09.25.pdf . When i enter in  the input "UPLOAD_COD" the number 2369, I want to delete the file 2015.03.12.pdf from server and be replaced with 2016.09.25.pdf, and in the LINK_DOWNLOAD column to be updated to the new link (folder/2015.03.12.pdf).
Thank you!

Comment: i don't see any attempt to actually do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want to delete the file with ID_PRODUCT = 2369? just fetch it's LINK_DOWNLOAD from database

You put this code after uploading and inserting your file

```
//first create a query that select the row of the data that you are finding
$currentSql = "Select * from download where ID_PRODUCT = '".$UPLOAD_COD."'";
$current = $conn->query($currentSql);


// then fetch it's result then unlink the file from the server
while($row = $current->fetch_assoc()) {
    $file = $row['LINK_DOWNLOAD'];
    // check if file is exist then delete
    if (file_exists($file)) {
        unlink($file);
    }
}
```

Comment: i have a error: **Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on string in C:\xampp\htdocs\...**

Comment: what php object are you using smtp or pdo or mysqli?

Comment: do not use PDO.

Comment: @ster you haven't answer my question yet

Comment: is MySQLi Procedural

Comment: could you screenshot your code where fetch_assoc()  error occurs

Comment: also your php script

Comment: [![Untitled2.png](http://s15.postimg.org/fmrftoiff/Untitled2.png)](http://postimg.org/image/sqx06dah3/)

Comment: it should be $row = $current->fetch_assoc() not $row = $currentSql->fetch_assoc()

Comment: you get the fetch_assoc of $current not $currentSql

Answer (score 1):

just add delete query after insert query is executed

```
$deleteSql = "Delete from download where ID_PRODUCT = '".$UPLOAD_COD."'";
$conn->query($deleteSql);
```

Comment: what do you mean multiply rows? multiple rows?

Comment: sorry, work (update value in the table) but not delete file from server,

Comment: ah so you want to delete file with ID_PRODUCT = 2369?

Answer (score 1):

You have to update the corresponding entry in your database :

```
UPDATE download SET LINK_DOWNLOAD='folder/2016.09.25.pdf' WHERE ID=1
```

I'm using the `WHERE` criteria on the `ID` column because you didn't tell if there was only one entry per product. If there is only one entry per product, the `LINK_DOWNLOAD` would also be right in the product table.

By looking at your table, you may have multiple download links for one product since it seems to be a linked table, so if you want to update one entry, maybe you want to update only this entry.

So in your code, I would add a block to look for an existing entry for the product_id input in `UPLOAD_COD`.

Then, if you're updating a link to a physical file, you have to remove/archive the initial file. So, you can look at the [file_exists](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php) php command, as weel as [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2371408/how-to-delete-a-file-via-php).

And to finish, I would process an update only if there is an existing entry for this product (and maybe you have other criterias, or at least, you can add others later if needed).

Hope this helps !