# PHP Unlink Delete Incorrect File Name

Tags: php

I want to make a function to delete a file in my folder through `php`. I've written the code based on suggestion from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2371431/9667363), but eventually it is not deleting the file I intended to remove. It's removing other file instead.
Here's the code :

```
$file_name = $this->input->post('file_name'); //getting file name from view

$path_gse = realpath('file_upload/station_report/gse_serviceability/'.$file_name);
if(is_writable($path_gse)) {
    unlink($path_gse);
}
```

In `$file_name` variable I pass it from view with `ajax`, I've tested it and it did return the correct file name. I really have no idea why this function delete the file that I don't intended to remove.

**UPDATE**

Here's the files in folder before I delete,
[image: file before delete]

Then I delete a row number 3 from html table,
[image: table stackoverflow]

It suppose to delete a file named `crew_conden-1801-Local_Time  ver download tgl 18 Jan 18`, but here's what happened,[image: file after delete]

It deleted `OTP Dashboard development` file instead of `crew_conden-1801-Local_Time  ver download tgl 18 Jan 18`

Comment: Highly relevant information regarding your issue is things like, your folder structure and file layout, what is sent in the `$file_name` variable and which file is wrongfully deleted in your eyes.

Comment: You don't need to use real path to delete files!

Comment: I finding it hard to believe that the issue is a bug in PHP, pretty sure there's something wrong with your code after all, but you didn't provide enough details to actually know what's going on

Comment: `echo $path_gse` to check for the path

Comment: Are you really running your script in the folder just below file_upload? I would recommend you to use the full path to the file, and not a current path relative path.  (e.g if file_upload is in /var/www make sure to start your path with that. So in your code the realpath row would be


    $path_gse = realpath('/var/www/file_upload/station_report/gse_serviceability/'.$file_name);

Comment: @inquam I've updated my question, please take a look.

Comment: @AlonEitan I've updated my question, please take a look.

Comment: Sounds like your “Delete” buttons are not be sending the correct file name to begin with. You likely made a mistake creating them, or the form/forms they are in, so that only the name of the last file is ever send.

Comment: @aan As  misorude wrote, try to inspect the delete button elements and see what value did you set to them

Comment: Have you done a check of the variable `$file_name` when you receive it so it contains what you expect on the backend? Do you encode the name when sending it?